# Theos replace a method call with another in the same class - Jailbreak required

Tags: objective-c, jailbreak, theos

Good Night :)
I want to replace a method call that's my class

```
Player

-(BOOL)checkDone:(NSString*)name;
-(BOOL)checkWrong:(NSString*)name;
```

I'm tryng to do

```
%hook Player
-(BOOL)checkDone:(NSString*)name{
return [self checkWrong:string];
%end
```

The compiler doesn't know where is the definition of checkWrong... it is in the class that I want to hook... but it doesn't compile...
How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
%hook Player
-(BOOL)checkWrong:(NSString*)name
{ 
    return %orig;
}
%end`
```

Also the format on your code has unbalanced brackets.